# A quadratic Approximation Function Expression

Tags: optimization, taylor-expansion, quadratics

I have very clear question. I'm searching about polynomial approximation.
[image: In this formula]

In this formula, it say's $$f = (z-z_2)(z-z_3).F_1 + (z-z_3)(z-z_1).F_2 + (z-z_1)(z-z_2)F_3$$

where $F_1 = \frac{f_1}{(z_1-z_2)(z_1-z_3)}$, etc.

I searched it and when we write quadratic approximation we can use taylor series and we can write f like this:

$$f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)\frac{f'(a)}{1!} + (x-a)^2\frac{f''(a)}{2!} +\ldots  $$

How it converts $f = (z-z_2)(z-z_3)\cdot F_1 + (z-z_3)(z-z_1)\cdot F_2 + (z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdot F_3$. What is the source of this formula? It doesn't similar to taylor series. I'm searching it for $3$ days but I can't understand how can we write it? What's the relation between this f expression and taylor series? Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

That is the formula for [Langrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial):

Given a set of $k+1$ data points
:$(x_0, y_0),\ldots,(x_j, y_j),\ldots,(x_k, y_k)$
where no two $x_j$ are the same, the '''interpolation polynomial in the Lagrange form''' is a linear combination
$$L(x) := \sum_{j=0}^{k} y_j \ell_j(x)$$
of Lagrange basis polynomials
:$$\ell_j(x) := \prod_{\begin{smallmatrix}0\le m\le k\\ m\neq j\end{smallmatrix}} \frac{x-x_m}{x_j-x_m} = \frac{(x-x_0)}{(x_j-x_0)} \cdots \frac{(x-x_{j-1})}{(x_j-x_{j - 1})} \frac{(x-x_{j+1})}{(x_j-x_{j+1})} \cdots \frac{(x-x_k)}{(x_j-x_k)},$$
where $0\le j\le k$.

In your context, you have $3$ points, hence we get a quadratic interpolation polynomial. It is the quadratic polynomial that passes through the $3$ points.

Comment: Thank u so much. You saved my day. My last question is what's the mean of "*" is it like j or i?

Comment: $z^*$ is the notation meant for the position where the interpolation quadratic function attains maximum value.